# Python bottle and gevent server running asynchronously?

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket, bottle, gevent

I have recently been working on a web-controlled speaker with a song request feature and I can't seem to have two browsers connected to the Web Socket at the same time. The server will still serve the browser the HTML, but not the data given by the Web Socket. I understand that I may need to use gevent's built-in greenlets, but I don't know if the same will apply for here, or if I will need to re-think my idea of the infinite loop. Can anyone help?

**Content of gevent-test.py:**

```
from bottle import request, Bottle, abort, static_file
app = Bottle()

open("playlist2.txt").close()

@app.route('/websocket')
def handle_websocket():
    wsock = request.environ.get('wsgi.websocket')
    if not wsock:
        abort(400, 'Expected WebSocket request.')

    while True:
        try:
            playlist = open("playlist2.txt", "r").readlines()
            playlistnew = open("playlist.txt", "r").readlines()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass
        except PermissionError:
            pass
        if playlist != playlistnew:
            try:
                playlist = open("playlist2.txt", "w")
                playlist.writelines(playlistnew)
                playlist.close()
            except FileNotFoundError:
                pass
            try:
                message = open("playlist2.txt", "r").read()
                print(message)
                wsock.send(message)
            except WebSocketError:
                break

@app.get('/home')
def homepage():
    return static_file("index.html", root=".")

from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from geventwebsocket import WebSocketError
from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler
server = WSGIServer(("127.0.0.1", 8080), app,
                    handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

**Contents of index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <h1>Now playing:</h1>
  <p id="now-playing"></p>
  <h1>Up Next:</h1>
  <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No.</th>
                <th>Song Title</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="playlist">

        </tbody>
  </table>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8080/websocket");
    ws.onopen = function() {};
    ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
        var file = (evt.data).split("\n");
        console.log(file);
        var table = document.getElementById("playlist");
        table.innerHTML = '';
        document.getElementById("now-playing").innerHTML = file[0]
        for(var i=1, len=file.length; i < len; i++){
            var number = (i);
            var name = (file[i]);
            console.log(file[i])
            console.log(i)
            var newrow = table.insertRow(-1);
            var numberCell = newrow.insertCell(0);
            numberCell.innerHTML = number
            var nameCell = newrow.insertCell(1);
            nameCell.innerHTML = name
        };
    };
  </script>
</head>
</html>
```

playlist.txt and playlist2.txt can contain whatever you want, but the web socket only serves data when you edit and save playlist.txt. It then edits playlist2.txt to match, then takes the new data and sends it.